# Scala scripting helper library

Tags: scala

is there any library that helps with evaluating scala code at runtime? Currently I've been using `scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain` but it feels pretty low level.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`Eval`](https://twitter.github.io/util/docs/#com.twitter.util.Eval) in the `twitter-util` library.